# Existing GUID column add FK Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

Ive got an existing table with a column thats a Guid which I added after a while so there is records in the table before which have a 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 value.

Now I want to add a FK in entity framework since this guid references another tables ID, but when I change the model from: Guid OtherDtoId -> myDto otherDtoId I run into the error: The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint.

Im aware that this error is due to the existing empty Guids doesnt have a corresponding guid in the other table. I thought I would get around this by setting the Guid OtherDtoId to nullable so that the 0000... ones wouldnt matter, but it doesnt seemt to solve it.

Is there a way to keep my records in the table and add a FK that is nullable? EF wanted to drop the column completely but that isnt possible since there is existing records present..

```
public class OriginalDto
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Guid OtherDtoId { get; set; } // I want to change this to public myDto otherDtoId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because OtherDtoId afte alter will be a FK and could not empty, so 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 could not be valid. You should deletes those 0000... records or update OtherDtoId to not-empty value before update database.

Comment: Yep thats what I finally did. Ran:

SELECT FK_column from FK_table
WHERE FK_column NOT IN
(SELECT PK_column from PK_table)

Which gave me what was missing/incorrect. Then after removing I ran:

ALTER TABLE FK_table NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK
UPDATE FK_table SET FK_ID = PK_ID

Then alter the table back with constraints:

ALTER TABLE FK_table WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT FK